# Location of the powershell profile on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, powershell

When executing the command `notepad $profile` an instance of notepad opens but I get a warning that the path doesn't exist.

So I'll have to set this manually, does anybody know how? There are a couple of locations, but I'd prefer to put the profile in the correct location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple profile scripts that can be created according to which hosts and how many users you wish the profile to apply to.  The PowerShell 2.0 help has an [about_Profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847857.aspx) article that goes into detail.  The short version (from the docs) is:

```
Description                Path
-----------                ----
Current User, Current Host $Home\[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1
Current User, All Hosts    $Home\[My ]Documents\Profile.ps1
All Users, Current Host    $PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
All Users, All Hosts       $PsHome\Profile.ps1

Name                               Description
-----------                        -----------
$Profile                           Current User,Current Host
$Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost    Current User,Current Host
$Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts       Current User,All Hosts
$Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost       All Users, Current Host
$Profile.AllUsersAllHosts          All Users, All Hosts
```

Comment: this is a wonderful answer, Keith.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a PowerShell script you can use to check for the existence of these profiles, and create them if they don't exist.

http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2009/11/get-profiles/

Comment: That is extremely usefull. Thanks for the help.